# Which are vector graphics based image format supported by iphone?

Tags: iphone, image, vector-graphics

I have developed one game for iphone which uses png images.It works well but which are the vector graphics images supported  by iphone that i can use for my game for better quality of image like when we zoom the image the image displayed properly.which are the most common image formats that are widely used by iphone game developers?

Answer (score 1):

The only vector graphics format that is directly supported on iOS is PDF (not counting `UIWebView`, which also supports SVG).

Vector graphics are not typically used in games, because they're much slower to render, but that depends on what type of game you're developing. I would consider using multiple versions of bitmap images with different resolutions for zooming.

Comment: i know that png is not vector based format other i have used for other image formats.

Comment: yes that is the option that i can make it to different resolutions but what are the image  formats that are used in the popular games like angry birds ?

Comment: Either PNG or PVR (compressed OpenGL texture format) I'd guess.

Answer (score 1):

I saw [this](https://github.com/mattrajca/SVGKit) on github a while back. It claims to render SVGs to Core Image layers. I've never used it, but I know it exists.

Comment: i have already tested it.It claims to render SVGs but does not work with all type of svg files.Have a look at other question asked by me for same thing.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624070/how-to-render-all-kind-of-svg-files-in-iphone